# How to call the Package and derived packages to print out?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am a beginner doing a program that prints out three types of shipping using Inheritance. I've got all the calculations out but now I am just trying to figure out how to print them all out. If someone could suggest something that could print out the input while also printing out how much each shipping option would cost that would be great.

```
// FDHPackage: a program that creates 3 package classes that calculate the 
//shipping costs based on the weight and the type of package it is (regular,       two day, or overnight.)

#include <string> // C++ standard string class
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Package // Base Class
{
private: // data members 
string infoS, infoR; //Sender and Recpient information
double weight;  // in ounce 
double cost;  // per ounce 

public: //member functions 
    void setInfoS(string infoS);
    void setInfoR(string infoR);

string getInfoS()
{
    return infoS;
}
string getInfoR()
{
    return infoR;
}

double calculateCost(double weight, double costPerOunce) //function that       calculate the cost z 
    {
    double zz;  //total cost = weight*cost per ounce 
    zz = weight * costPerOunce;  //the cost zz

    cout << "The Regular Cost = " << zz << endl << endl;
    return zz;
}
   }; // end class Package

  void Package::setInfoS(string senInfo)
{
        infoS = senInfo;
 }


  void Package::setInfoR(string recInfo)
  {
        infoR = recInfo;
  }

  class TwoDayShipping : public Package // derived class
 {
public:
    double calcShippingCost(double weight, double costPerOunce, double        regularFee)
    /* function that calculate shipping cost by adding the flat fee to the weight-based cost
    calculated by base class Package’s calculateCost function*/
{
    double z; //shippingcost of Two day Package class

    z = calculateCost(weight, costPerOunce) + regularFee;
    cout << "The TwoDayPackage Cost = " << z << endl;
    return z;
}
  private:
    double regularFee;
   }; // end TwoDayShipping

 class OvernightShipping : public Package //derived class that adds the     additional fee per ounce
         {
          public:
                double calcCostOvernight(double weight, double costPerOunce, double      additionalCost)
{
    double cc; //shippingcost of overnight class
    cc = calculateCost(weight, costPerOunce) + (additionalCost * weight);

    cout << "The OvernightShipping Cost = " << cc << endl;
    return cc;
}
 private:
    double overnightCost; //per ounce 
    }; // end class OvernightShipping

 int main()
 {
    string customerInfo;
    float packageWeight;
    double costPerOunce;
    double regularFee;
    double additionalCost;

Package base;   //the object base of the package class 
TwoDayShipping twoday;  //the object twoday of the first inherited class 
OvernightShipping overnight;   //the object overnight of the second    inherited calss   

cout << " *-*-Welcome to United Postal Services-*-*" << endl << endl;
cout << "Please Enter Required Data: " << endl;;

cout << "Enter Weight" << endl;
cin >> packageWeight;
cout << endl;
cout << "Enter Cost Per Ounce" << endl;
cin >> costPerOunce;
cout << endl; 

cout << "Regular rate would cost: ";


 }
```

Comment: `cout << base.calculatePackage(packageWeight, costPerOunce) << endl;`...?

Comment: Whats the question? @immibis

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JFRa7Ovym8s

Comment: @FrancisHeroux I believe it's "How to call the Package and derived packages to print out?"

Comment: Too much code.  Minimal working example, please.

Comment: @immibis Gotcha gotcha, but when I do use that it says that "Package has no member called "calculatePackage"?

Comment: @FrancisHeroux Because I meant to say `calculateCost` and your brain is currently turned off so you didn't notice my mistake.

Comment: @immibis Like I said, I am new to C++ and I appreciate your help and I would also appreciate your patience with me. I did that but now it says Twoday and Overnight cannot take two arguments?         

 `cout << "Enter Weight" << endl;
 cin >> packageWeight;
 cout << endl;
 cout << "Enter Cost Per Ounce" << endl;
 cin >> costPerOunce;
 cout << endl; 

 cout << base.calculateCost(packageWeight, costPerOunce) << endl;
 cout << twoday.calcShippingCost(packageWeight, costPerOunce) << endl;
 cout << overnight.calcCostOvernight(packageWeight, costPerOunce) << endl; `

Comment: That's because they don't take two arguments.

Comment: @immibis Alright, so what is your suggestion to print out the two night and over night shipping costs?

Comment: I suggest using your brain... You wrote some functions that take three arguments, you tried to call them with two arguments, the compiler complained that they don't have two arguments because they have three which means you need to pass three...

Comment: @immibis Of course!!! Thanks so much. Last thing, the output keeps printing out "Regular Cost" in between every other output for some reason and I can't seem to figure out how to make it stop at only printing out once?

Comment: @FrancisHeroux Well that's because you made it print that when `calculateCost` is called, and you're calling `calculateCost` each time. Maybe don't make `calculateCost` print that.